# EXCEL - is there a formula to copy all the cells containing specific text to another column?

Tags: excel

I have a column with dates (starting in b82), in this format 26-01-2017(**DD-MM-YYYY**). I want that all the cells containing "-01-" (therefore all the dates of January) to be copied in another column starting from cell b10. Is there a formula in Microsoft Excel 2016 which can solve my problem??

this is the column with the range of dates

https://i.stack.imgur.com/waUyN.png

and here is the column B10 under which i want that the dates of a specific month are shown (from the list of the previous screenshot), for example all january dates....then i will have a simillar table where all the february will be needed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0DOX.png

so for example for january it should take all the values with "-01-" and put them under b10..here is how it should look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpoWq.png

Comment: [`IF` Function](https://support.office.com//article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

Comment: Which is it, **B10** or **B82** ???

Comment: B82 contains a loooong list of dates of, i want excel to take all the ones of january (containing -01-) to be copied in column B10

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you want all duplicates removed?

Comment: @ashleedawg please can you specify? i used IF function but how to use it in this case where i am looking only a specific text inside the column in a range? thanks!

Comment: @M. Wise, yes the B82 contains all different dates, there is no duplicates i am sure, from this long list of dates I want all the dates of  january to be copied under B10 :)

Comment: Are the dates in B82 in "text" format?

Comment: currently are in "date" format...

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(B$82:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/(MONTH(B$82:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))=1), ROW(1:1)))
```

Format as date and fill down.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this into Cell B10:

```
=MIN(IF(MONTH($B$82:$B$280)=1,$B$82:$B$280))
```

You will need to change $B$280 to the cell at the end of your date range.  This is an array formula, so you will need to press CTRL + Shift + Enter for it to work.  Then you will need to enter this formula into cell B11:

```
=MIN(IF(MONTH($B$82:$B$280)=1,IF($B$82:$B$280>B10,$B$82:$B$280)))
```

This is another array formula.  You can then drag it down 30 rows or so until the dates begin to repeat.

This is what is should look like:

[image]

Comment: dammit, it keep saying "there is a problem with this formula" :(

Comment: I've added a screenshot of how it should look.  I'm guessing there is a data type issue here, such as a date stored as text or something else.  Is there a green triangle next to the dates?

Comment: this is the column with the range of dates

https://i.stack.imgur.com/waUyN.png

and here is the column B10 under which i want that the dates of a specific month are shown (from the list of the previous screenshot), for example all january dates....then i will have a simillar table where all the february will be needed

https://i.imgur.com/TFGXuoe.png

so for example for january it should take all the values with "-01-" and put them under b10..here is how it should look like:

https://i.imgur.com/wGIybZx.png

Answer (score 0):

this is the column with the range of dates

https://i.stack.imgur.com/waUyN.png

and here is the column B10 under which i want that the dates of a specific month are shown (from the list of the previous screenshot), for example all january dates....then i will have a simillar table where all the february will be needed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0DOX.png

so for example for january it should take all the values with "-01-" and put them under b10..here is how it should look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpoWq.png

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the dates and formulas?

Comment: i did. please see above :)

Comment: Without seeing the spreadsheet, I'm not sure what would be causing that error.  Usually errors with array formulas give a #VALUE or something similar.  Most of the times I receive a "there is a problem with this formula" error comes from accidentally typing a random character, such as "\", somewhere in my formula.